# maven build jar with test resources file only

Tags: maven, jar

I have a project which will be built has jar.

structure of project as below

```
> src | - main
>       |- java
>        - resources 
>     | - test
>       | - resources
```

so now i want to create 2 jar files using maven 
1) main/java and main/resources
2) main/java and test/resources

My POM

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.tool.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never specified what is happening for you that is not what you're after, but looking at your example, it looks like you've got two different versions of the same plugin defined in your POM to try and hack what you want.

You can do what you're after by using the `<execution>` tag to define the desired behavior.

```
<plugin>
    <!-- jar plugin -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- use these to define different execution tasks during the package phase -->
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${project.mainClass}</mainClass>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>test-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>                       
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>                         <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After running this, you should have two jar's in your output directory, one named `[your artifactID]-[version].jar` and one named `[your artifactID]-[version]-tests.jar`